# iSCSI not mounting at boot

Tags: linux, debian, mount, debian-wheezy

So I have setup an iSCSI disk with open-iscsi.
I can connect and mount the disk, write and unmount manually.

And I entered the related definition to fstab too, which is smt. like:

```
dev/sdb1     /storage    ext3    defaults,auto,_netdev    0    0
```

It mounts manually without any problem.

However when I run `service open-iscsi restart` it fails to mount. It doesn't mount either on boot. If I write `mount` right after service fails to mount, it mounts...

This is the init script output:

```
[ ok ] Unmounting iscsi-backed filesystems: Unmounting all devices marked _netdev.
[....] Disconnecting iSCSI targets:Logging out of session [sid: 1, target: iqn.***.c44c07, portal: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx,3260]
Logout of [sid: 1, target: iqn.***.c44c07, portal: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx,3260] successful.
. ok
[ ok ] Stopping iSCSI initiator service:.
[ ok ] Starting iSCSI initiator service: iscsid.
[....] Setting up iSCSI targets:
Logging in to [iface: default, target: iqn.***.c44c07, portal: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx,3260] (multiple)
Login to [iface: default, target: iqn.***.c44c07, portal: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx,3260] successful.
. ok
[FAIL] Mounting network filesystems: failed!
```

This is what dmesg says (There is conn error but I don't get what's happening)

```
[ 4465.046920]  connection1:0: detected conn error (1020)
[ 4465.361580] Loading iSCSI transport class v2.0-870.
[ 4465.365419] iscsi: registered transport (tcp)
[ 4465.373846] iscsi: registered transport (iser)
[ 4465.652981] scsi13 : iSCSI Initiator over TCP/IP
[ 4465.911595] scsi 13:0:0:0: Direct-Access     QNAP     iSCSI Storage    3.1  PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[ 4465.913133] sd 13:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[ 4465.917664] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdb] 2097152000 512-byte logical blocks: (1.07 TB/1000 GiB)
[ 4465.921695] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[ 4465.921699] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 2f 00 00 00
[ 4465.929650] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: disabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[ 4465.974938]  sdb: sdb1
[ 4465.980409] sd 13:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
```

Notes:

- No username/password is used to connect to the target since it's internal network
- I added the node manually by `iscsiadm -m node -T "iqn.***.c44c07" -p xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -o new`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using UUID instead of device name in the fstab file solved the issue.